# Why don't you define every variables in the global scope

Tags: javascript, scope

I am learning javascript and today i'm learning about the scope chain.

So apparently you can access the variable of the global scope even inside 3rd or 4th function scope.
I don't really get why wouldn't you declare all of your variables in the global scope to be able to access them everywhere and every function that you create ?

so why not :

```js
var a = 'Hello!';
var b = 'Hey!';
var c = 'Hola!';

function first (){
//some function you want to do
second();

  function second () {
  console.log(a + b + c);
  }
}
```

Instead of :

```js
var a = 'Hello!';

function first (){
//some function you want to do
var b = 'Hey!';
second();

  function second () {
  var c = 'Hola!';
  console.log(a + b + c);
  }
}
```

Comment: [design patterns - Why is Global State so Evil? - Software Engineering Stack Exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil)

Comment: The primary reason is that in a web browser the global scope is horribly polluted with symbols pre-defined by the browser. For example, if you want a variable called "name", that will not work if declared globally. In general, for *all* programming languages the global scope is regarded as a resource to be used as little as possible.

Comment: global variables waste lot of `momory`. Local variables live only withing the block scope and thus save lot to memory. If you have big application and declare all global variables that would be considerable memory. Also you can't use that variable name anywhere else